# Monitor Tomcats internal threadpool without using JMX in a Spring Boot App

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jvisualvm, mbeans

I have a simple Spring Boot web application set up for handling incoming http requests.

Using the Java VisualVm I am able to see MBeans such as Tomcat's internal Threadpool. See the following screenshot:

[Screenshot of the Java VisualVM's MBean viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkqJb.png)

I have successfully used JMX to monitor attributes such as "currentThreadCount" and "currentThreadsBusy". I set up Prometheus to access the monitored attributes as well. This works well.

However, now I wanted to know if it is possible to access these values without using JMX?
I noticed that the abstract class https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint.html contains a method called getCurrentThreadCount().
The class Nio2Endpoint (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/Nio2Endpoint.html) extends AbstractEndpoint. So I imagine that this might be a way to retrieve these values.

Unfortunately I am not able to access the endpoints in any way. Can anybody tell me if it is possible at all to access them without using JMX?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are Tomcat internal classes, they're not accessible to your webapp. You would have to actually build your own version of Tomcat to access those classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was afraid I would have to change actual Tomcat source code in order to access them.
Is there anything that I can do with Java reflection to help me out?

Comment: Is there a reason why you *don't* want to use a standard way of accessing that information, i.e. JMX? Trying to access the container classes from your webapp would be a really ugly hack, that is if you succeeded in it.

Comment: Mainly out of curiousity. While JMX works well for the task, I was wondering if there was another way.
I'm successfully using a custom Prometheus controller for collecting Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool statistics (autowiring org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) and I was wondering if could do something similar with Tomcat's internal thread pool.